# EventBus emitting more than once until page refresh

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I am using the EventBus in Vue.js to send data from one method to another. I have two methods, let's say `one()` and `two()`. I am using EventBus as follows:

```
one() {
  EventBus.$emit("this:that", data);
}
```

And then I have in my other method something like this

```
two() {
  EventBus.$on('this:that', data => {
    window.open(data.link, '_blank');
  });
}
```

When I call the method `one()` the first time it opens a new tab, however if I call it for a second time it opens twice the same tab, if I call it for the third time it opens three times the same tab and so on until I refresh the page and call it again then it only opens one tab. I tried using `EventBus.$once` however it didn't open a tab at all.

How would I be able to only open a tab no matter how many times the method is call before refreshing the page. i.e. I call it three times and for the three calls it only generates a new tab each time not one, then two and then three tabs.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Seems like you are calling the method two too much. How does this method is called ?

Comment: The issue is in the code that is not posted here, i think you might be calling the two method more than once. Two method adds an event listener whenever it is called, so number of times you call two() = number of tabs opened

Comment: I call the method `two()` every time the user click on a button, to create a new entity and display it in another tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guessed you don't call `EventBus.$off("this:that")` to unregister your eventBus. So it will be fired increasingly.

Comment: It worked, thank you very much. Before I was just using `EventBus.$off()` that's why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

Always have a habit of removing event listeners from the event bus that's listening to the event as below.

```
 beforeDestroy(){
    EventBus.$off('event-bus-name')
  }
```